# Three entities and integrity constraint

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have three entities:

- School
- Schooltype
- Branch

With following relation:

- Schooltype to School (One to Many)
- Schooltype to Branch (One to Many)
- Branch to School (One to Many)

If i update my database structure "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" i receive following error message.

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE school ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F99EDABBDCD6CC49 FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES schooltype_branch (id)':
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ebm2`.`#sql-3cf_e6e`, CONSTRAINT `FK_F99EDABBDCD6CC49` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `schooltype_branch`
   (`id`))
```

But i do not find my mistake, can somebody give me a hint for this issue?

I will also show some relevant parts of my three entities:

**School:**

```
class School implements BuildingInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SchoolType", inversedBy="schools")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schooltype_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $schooltype;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SchooltypeBranch", inversedBy="school")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $branch;
}
```

**Schooltype:**

```
class SchoolType implements BuildingTypeInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\School", mappedBy="schooltype")
     */
    protected $schools;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\SchooltypeBranch", mappedBy="schooltype")
     */
    protected $branch;  
}
```

**Schooltype Branch:**

```
class SchooltypeBranch
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SchoolType", inversedBy="branch")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schooltype_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $schooltype;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\School", mappedBy="branch")
     */
    protected $school;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a foreign key constraint is failing, like if `school` table has a `branch_id` not present in `schooltype_branch` table.

Comment: But i define the reference between school and branch like this @ORM\JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName="id"). "branch_id" only exists in School Entity which is related to the id of the SchooltypeBranch Entity.

Comment: Does your schema validate? php app\console doctrine:schema:validate

Comment: Now i solve the issue. I remove all records from the table "Schooltype_branch" and rebuild the table structure. Now everything is fine, many thanks for your support